# How can I change my name in TF2 without having to change it in the Steam overlay?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Apparently, they removed the command `setinfo name "your name"` and it doesn't do anything anymore.

Is there another way to change your TF2 name while in-game?

Comment: I believe the Steam overlay is the only way, but I am not confident enough to write this as an answer.

Comment: It could be that you're playing on a server that has manually disabled the command, not necessarily that it has been removed

Comment: @Robotnik, I read in a few forums that they disabled it to avoid a exploit of some kind

Comment: @jmfsg - Ah ok. Do you still have the source? If so, could you add it? (Telling a diamond what to do, scary business :P)

Comment: @Robotnik http://trhservers.com/Forum/index.php?topic=3130.0

Comment: @jmfsg - 100% uber? Damn. I found out about this too late!

Comment: @Robotnik I can't tell if you're being sarcastic, but the real exploit was users changing their names to avoid being kicked.

Comment: @AustinMohr - I was being serious, sorry for the confusion :). That's a lot less intriguing than the 100% uber.

Comment: Not exactly a fix, but can't you just save your old name and set it back after you're done being someone different? I know this is probably not what you're looking for but it needed to be said at least.  It's not that hard to change Steam names after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, the Steam overlay is the only way you can change your in-game name. There just isn't any other way.

However, a while back, there WAS a way: Type "setinfo name (NAME)" in the console. This has however, been removed from the game and cannot be used.

Source: Looking through a bagillion sites.

Comment: Yes, it was removed in an effort to stop those, all too common, hackers that constantly change their names so as not to be vote kicked.

Comment: Too weak of a solution to be honest, they could have limited it to 1 change every hour, or session, or something like that. Well, too bad then.

Comment: @jmfsg Agreed >.>

Comment: Valve keeps everything excessively simple. Case in point: it kicks you out of upgrade UI when someone joins or leaves and discards what you did.

Comment: @doug65536 Wait, that is not a bug?